# Android Studio 'device not found' but it installs the apk on physical device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am developing on Android studio 1.4

When i run apps on my physical device, AS does copy them to the device and launches the session. When i look at the debugger it shows no output and i get the error

`00-00 00:00:00.0 0-0/? E/Internal: device '03da6ee58291eff4' not found`

Any idea how to debug this?

EDIT: extra information, i can see the device on the Device Monitor.

Comment: I had the same issue. I think the error was from Android Studio's side. I just needed logcat so Command Prompt > `adb logcat` did it for me

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
sudo adb kill-server && sudo adb start-server
```

Or

`adb kill-server && adb start-server`

I hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez okay okay .Did you solve this ?

Comment: No. The issue comes and goes, not sure what the problem is.